# Connecting 2 computers WIN 7 and Ubuntu 15.1 using Crossover cable to share an internet connection

Tags: networking

I have a desktop computer with Windows 7 and laptop with Ubuntu 15.1 installed. I wanna connect an ethernet cable(Crossover) to share an internet connection(internet works in my desktop). How can I do this???

Comment: 15.1?  Do you mean 15.04 or 15.10?

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect the crossover (ethernet) cable to both computers. They may remain powered on while you do this.
2. On the **Windows** computer, open the **Start** menu and type "Ncpa.cpl". This should display the networking connections. (**This is assuming the Windows computer is the one with the current internet connection!**)
3. Right click the internet connection, click **Properties** and then the **Sharing** tab.
4. Check the box next to "Allow other network users to connect through..."
5. Open a web browser on the **Linux** machine and check that it is connected.

   - I adapted this answer from this source:
     http://techin.oureverydaylife.com/share-internet-using-crossover-cable-13475.html
     Please check it out if you have any problems, or share them here.

Good luck!